# Difference in return order?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Javascript is there a difference between:

```
return setTimeout(this._onTimeout, 1000*secs);
```

and

```
setTimeout(this._onTimeout, 1000*secs);
return;
```

The former does not always run the timeout, but the latter always does. So it feels like there is a difference, but my google-fu is failing to find the reason.

Comment: Are you stepping through the code? What is a typical value of `secs`?

Comment: The code is being run in expressjs. `secs` and be anywhere from 1 to a few hours worth of seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> return setTimeout(this._onTimeout, 1000*secs);
```

> and

```
> setTimeout(this._onTimeout, 1000*secs); return;
```

> The former does not always run the timeout, but the latter always does

You have that backwards. If the code executes correctly, the first will **always** return a reference to the *setTimeout* that can be used to cancel it. The second will **always** return *undefined*. Any other behaviour is not confomrant with ECMA–262.

If you are getting some other behaviour, there are errors in the code or what you have posted isn't what is being run.

Comment: If this is part of a function whose return value is then used with a clearTimeout, then the first example would not allways execute (if the clearTimeout is executed on time). This is an assumpiton though, and we need more code to see if and why the first timeout is failing.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. The timeout can't be cancelled until after it is called. Since it is called by the return statement, if it is called at all then a reference to it must be returned to the caller. What the caller then does with the reference is only known to the OP — and perhaps not then either. :-).

Comment: What I mean is that if the returning timeout Id of the first function is then used on a clearTimeout BEFORE the timeout ocurrs, then the operation will be canceled, thus making like the timeout wasn't executed at all.

Answer (score 1):

If it were being used like this:

```
var obj = {
  set1 : function(secs) {
    return setTimeout(this._onTimeout, 1000*secs);
  },
  set2 : function(secs) { 
    setTimeout(this._onTimeout, 1000*secs);
    return;
  },
  _onTimeout : function() {
     alert("worked");
  }
};
clearTimeout(obj.set1(1));
clearTimeout(obj.set2(1));
```

Only the second line would cause _onTimeout to actually fire.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference.
Try to run this code:

```
(function() {
    return setTimeout(function(){console.log(1)}, 500);
})();
(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)}, 500);
    return;
})();
```

`return` doesn't affect on setTimeout call in JS interpreter.

Comment: You missed the point—the difference is that the first returns a reference to the *setTimeout*, the second returns *undefined*.

Comment: question was about behavior of `setTimeout` not about `return`